# Oracle Apex custom tags in report templates

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am creating a report template for an oracle apex application. I created a custom tag such as #TITLE#, when I run my report the data does not show up, it just shows #TITLE#. To be more specific here is my code.

### Report Template (Column Template 1)

```
<td#ALIGNMENT# headers="#COLUMN_HEADER_NAME#" class="data">#TITLE#</td>
```

So in my Column Template 1 the custom tag #TITLE# is where I want my data from the query to be placed. This is my query

```
SELECT f.filename AS TITLE
FROM files f
```

In my report I have selected my custom report template. I know I am probably missing some configuration checkbox to make the data recognize the custom tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In APEX there are 2 kinds of report template: column template and row template.
[image]

You need the row template version but have picked the column template version, which only allows the generic #COLUMN_VALUE# rather than specific named columns.